# grant permission to a file(s) for IIS6.0 from command line

Tags: command-line, iis-6, file-permissions

I'm trying to grant permission to a file from the command line for the user `IIS6.0`.

So far I've tried `icacls /grant ISS_WPG:(RX,W) 'namefile'`, but with no result.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:

```
icacls FILE /grant USER:(RX,W)
```

filename first.